# access violation in CascadeObjectDetector using modified XML file

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, cascade-classifier, viola-jones

I modified the OpenCV XML file (classifier) which is generated by `TrainCascadeObjectDetector` of MATLAB, I deleted some items.

When i tried to load it with:

```
detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('classifier.xml');
```

I get an access violation error:

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.5372-1:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Access violation detected at Fri May 20 19:11:24 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration:
Crash Decoding      : Disabled
Crash Mode          : continue (default)
Current Graphics Driver: Microsoft Corporation GDI Generic Version 1.1.0
Default Encoding    : windows-1252
Graphics card 1     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Version 8.15.10.2559
Host Name           : USER
MATLAB Architecture : win64
MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b
MATLAB Version      : 8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)
OpenGL              : software
Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 7 Édition Intégrale 
Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
Window System       : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Fault Count: 1
Abnormal termination:
Access violation
Register State (from fault):
RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00000000f7f42080
RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 000000008b655de8
RSP = 00000000f7f41ec0  RBP = 0000000000000001
RSI = 000000001c19e060  RDI = 000000008aeb33c0
R8 = 000000013cfe36b0   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 000000000001d940  R11 = 0000000000000001
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 000000001c19dfd4
RIP = 00000000b8ad68c1  EFL = 00010206
   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b
Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000000b8ad68c1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_objdetect249.dll+00026817
[  1] 0x00000000b8ae9f91 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_objdetect249.dll+00106385 cv::CascadeClassifier::runAt+00000481
[  2] 0x00000000b8adba84 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_objdetect249.dll+00047748 cv::FileNodeIterator::operator*+00000820
[  3] 0x00000000b8576134 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_core249.dll+01335604 cv::ParallelLoopBody::~ParallelLoopBody+00000436
[  4] 0x00000000b85759bc C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_core249.dll+01333692 cv::Formatter::setDefault+00003036
[  5] 0x00000000b85763d3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\opencv_core249.dll+01336275 cv::currentParallelFramework+00000147
[  6] 0x000007fefb7cc882   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\tbb.dll+00116866 tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_wait+00013042
[  7] 0x000007fefb7c9f5f   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\tbb.dll+00106335 tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_wait+00002511
[  8] 0x000007fefb7c6d84   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\tbb.dll+00093572 tbb::task_scheduler_init::terminate+00003428
[  9] 0x000007fefb7c12a8   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\tbb.dll+00070312 tbb::internal::thread_yield_v3+00004488
[ 10] 0x000007fefb7c154b   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\tbb.dll+00070987 tbb::internal::thread_yield_v3+00005163
[ 11] 0x000007fef07a3fef C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\MSVCR110.dll+00147439 beginthreadex+00000263
[ 12] 0x000007fef07a4196 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\MSVCR110.dll+00147862 endthreadex+00000402
[ 13] 0x00000000776d652d                   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll+00091437 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[ 14] 0x0000000077a1c521                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00181537 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033
If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/
A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.
Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: OpenCV expects the file to have a certain structure, you cant just delete stuff...

Comment: You're right.@Amro